# How to grab using getAttribute or SetAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
init: function(element, options) {
    this.$generic = element.find('.love');
    this.type     = this.$generic.data('type');
    this.url      = this.$generic.attr('href');
    this.$count   = this.$generic.setAttribute('data-love-count');
    console.log(this.$count + ' 6');
    //this.count = +this.$count.text();
},
```

```
<a data-love-count="${loveCount}" href="/love/${session.userId}">
    <i class="icn-heart"></i>
    ${loved}
</a>
```

The console.log keeps on giving errors; `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I am not sure why. I tried to use `getAttribute` or `setAttribute` but I get same errors.

Also I couldn't figure how to add the loves as in commented line. Everytime user clicks, love will increase.

Comment: `setAttribute` requires two paramters. Also why don't you use jQuery's `attr()`? Please post your full code so we can help you...

Comment: @enyce12 - I just looked up and realized that it only takes in two parameters. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$count = this.$generic.setAttribute('data-love-count');
```

You're using a html attribute `setter` there, to `get` the data. replace that line with:

```
this.$count = this.$generic.attr('data-love-count');
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: thanks - but if love is increased, how do i add $count?

Comment: What do you mean? This saves the value in the `'data-love-count'` attribute to `$count`

Comment: will need to display different number each time the different users click on love. Int will only have the initial number we see

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute` and `getAttribute` are native functions but your `$generic` variable is a jQuery object.

jQuery uses `.attr` instead: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

If you wanted your code to work you could do:

`this.$count = +this.$generic[0].getAttribute('data-love-count');`

(Note that it is get not set, and the `+` converts it to a number type)

[get](https://api.jquery.com/get/) `0` will access the first native element that the jQuery selector found, which you can then call native methods on.

To increment:

`this.$count += 6;`

Comment: How does `$generic.get(0)` differ from `$generic[0]`?

Comment: @DominicTobias - thanks and would it work on setAttribute as well? Just update: i tried your example but it returns errors: cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: They are the same except it checks that the number exists, also I don't think [0] works in ECMAScript 4 (but who cares) - both would be fine

Comment: @kittymeows looking at your code it is `loveCount` that changes and probably is supposed to re-render the template when it does. But anyhow if you wanted to manually increment the attribute you could do  `this.$generic[0].setAttribute('data-love-count', 7586)` or `this.$generic.attr('data-love-count', 7586)`

Comment: @DominicTobias thanks for explaining, but increasing the love count would be dynamic. hmm.

Comment: @DominicTobias - think init should be get Attribute. then update should be setAttribute?

Comment: @kittymeows yes it should, if you can set something up on jsfiddle then I can better understand what you are doing. What libraries/template engine/framework are you using? Some would auto-update a view (template) if a variable changes so the implementation depends on what you are using. You probably don't need the data attribute at all - init: set count to a number, listen to click event, increment counter and re-render template

Comment: @DominicTobias - Grails and CanJS. It is not possible to set up jsfiddle when it is done in grails? init: set count to 0, then listen to click event and increase count?